# REPL arithmetic - Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’

Tags: haskell

I get the following error

> Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
> prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved."

when I type this simple expression into the winghci console:

`(1.0 * (floor 5))/(1.0 * (floor 5))`

I've read in other SO posts that you can't use the "/" division for integers, but here I'm trying to divide fractional numbers.

Comment: The problem is not `(/)` itself, but the fact that `floor` will return an `Integral` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor) returns values of a type that is a member of the `Integral` typeclass. Furthermore [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) requires the operands and the result to be all of *same* type and that type should be a member of the `Fractional` typeclass.

While in Haskell it is technically possible to make a type that is both a member of the `Integral` and the `Fractional` typeclass, it makes not much sense, and there is definitely no such standard type.

You thus will need to convert the result of the `floor` back to a type that can be fractional, for example by using [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```
Prelude> (1.0 * fromIntegral (floor 5))/(1.0 * fromIntegral (floor 5))
1.0
```

Comment: I expected the multiplication by 1.0 to do the conversion from Integral to Fractional.

Comment: @zslevi: no, [`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-) means the two operands and the result all have the same type. It is imho unsafe that programming languages do that, since each implicit conversion can have "information loss", and then the programmer is often not aware of that.